# border between two columns without height speified

Tags: html, css

I've got two columns and i need to add line between them. This is 1px solid color so i would love to achieve this with css. 
The trick is that content is dynamicaly loaded, so sometimes the left column can have more text and sometimes right column can have more text. Of course if the size of coulmn would be always the same i would add the border to bigger one. But unfortunatly i don't.

So is there a way to achieve this or do i have combine it with php and maybe strlen or something?

You can find simple code for this problem here http://jsfiddle.net/M9TSs/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way of doing it would be to have a border on both, and use a negative 1px margin to pull the right column over so that the borders overlap:

http://jsfiddle.net/7GCff/

Comment: Omg, there was a flash of that thought in my mind for a second but i did not catch this. Thank you. this is it. I don't want to use js if i don't have to. thank you :o)

Comment: @brianreavis This is old, but why the heck do people do it any other way than this? This is pure gold, why deal with table-cell when we can do this? Love it.

Answer (score 1):

I already solved this using JQuery...

I used this code and it worked great.

```
function equalHeight(group) {
    var tallest = 0;
    group.each(function() {
        var thisHeight = $(this).height();
        if(thisHeight > tallest) {
            tallest = thisHeight;
        }
    });
    group.height(tallest);
}
```

Source : http://www.cssnewbie.com/equal-height-columns-with-jquery/

Makes all columns have the same height as the longest.